# AlarmManager.RTC not delivered after device wakes up

Tags: android

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the document.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pi);
```

Basically every morning I want to show one notification. I've used AlarmManager.RTC as the user will see the notification when he wakes his/her phone. As per documentation if the phone is sleeping this even will fire when phone wakes up next time. But in my case if my phone is awake at 5 in the morning the notification fires else it doesn't.

> This alarm does not wake the device up; if it goes off while the device
>   is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device
>   wakes up.

So if the user wakes up the device at 8 AM this alarm wont' fire?